# Can you force include a C++ header file in local files ONLY (Visual Studio 2022)?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm experimenting with macros, such as replacing `==` with `is`, to make the syntax of **C++** closer to **C#**. When I force include a header file containing these macros (i.e. `#define is ==`), it seems files even outside of my project are affected.

Example:
`*bool __CLR_OR_THIS_CALL is(mask _Maskval, _Elem _Ch) const {*`

in *xlocale* becomes
`*bool __CLR_OR_THIS_CALL == (mask _Maskval, _Elem _Ch) const {*`.

I only want these macros to be included in my source files, but I don't want to have to manually include the header file with the macro definitions in every file of my project. Can you configure the force include (/FI) feature of Visual Studio Community to be used only on source files?

Comment: Where do you do `#define is ==`?  Do you do it before including the system headers?

Comment: Don't do that. Just don't do that. If you want to program in another language, then use that language. Don't try to shoehorn it into other languages. That benefits no one, not even yourself, and no one else will want to work with your code.

Comment: @NathanOliver I'm doing "#define is ==" in a '.h' file that I've added to the list of files to Force Include in visual studio

Comment: _"...Can you configure the force include (/FI) feature of Visual Studio Community to be used only on source files?..."_ that's exactly what it does - from the docs - "_...This option has the same effect as specifying the file with double quotation marks in an #include directive on the __first line of every source file__ ..."_ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/fi-name-forced-include-file?view=msvc-170 .  But it's probably not what you want.

Comment: @RichardCritten I'm confused, then, because the program runs fine when I #include the header in every source file manually

Comment: @lunkums as the very 1st line ?

Comment: @RichardCritten Not the 1st line for all them, but typically the second or third line either after a #pragma once or a #include <iostream>

Comment: *"make the syntax of C++ closer to C#..."* seems like a bad idea.

Comment: If you're coding stuff like `if(foo is 10)` instead of `if(foo == 10)` even in C# I'm rather skeptical that anyone would consider that a reasonable practice. Just use the `==` like millions of other programmers.

Comment: When you include `#define is ==` prior to any other includes, then it also applies that same definition to all other included files. Forcing an include essentially puts it first, thus all `is`, including in headers, are replaced by `==`. You cannot do what you want, and, as others have said, you should not. In C#, you should probably be using `==` anyway, since `is` is not meant for that purpose.

Comment: This is an interesting question. The asker is going to do something high-risk with it and I hope to not see it spread, but there's nothing wrong with the question.

Answer (score 1):

`#include "x.h"`  is a blunt instrument.

It literally replaces the include directive with the entire contents of *x*. In the case of Visual Studio's `/FI` feature it inserts the entire contents of *x* before the rest of the source file. Thus any macros that are defined in *x* included before  *y* -- by whatever means, include order, via `/FI`, etc. -- will affect *y*.

Comment: So the include gets added before anything else which affects the **xlocale** file which gets included right after. Got it.